# Duplicating of string and no newline when writing to a file

Tags: android, file

my application is suppose to record the amount of time taken when clicking the image. Therefore the string is being written to a file. Every time the user click the image, the savetext function will be called. But my output always have a duplicate of the string? Can anyone advice me on this?

```
public void saveText(){
        int seconds;
        String saveText;
        long elapsedMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mChronometer.getBase();
        seconds = (int) (elapsedMillis / 1000);
        saveText = String.valueOf(seconds);
        try {
            FileOutputStream writer = openFileOutput("logs.txt", MODE_APPEND);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(writer));
            out.write(saveText);
            out.newLine();
            out.close();
        } catch (Throwable t){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

This is where i call my save text:

```
public void drawCircle() {
    mChronometer = new Chronometer(this);
    final LinearLayout button_container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_window);
    final ImageButton imgView = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.gameass);
    imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.gameass);
    imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    int x = (int) (Math.random() * (button_container.getWidth() - imgView.getWidth()));
    int y = (int) (Math.random() * (button_container.getHeight() - imgView.getHeight()));
    button_container.setPadding(x, y, 0, 0);
    startTimer();
    imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            saveText();
            stopTimer();
            resetTimer();
            imgView.setImageDrawable(null);
            score++;
            counterTouch++;
            tempScore = String.valueOf(score);
            textViewScore.setText(tempScore);
            drawCircle();
        }
    });

}
```

I using another activity to view the logs.

```
private void readfromFile() {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("logs.txt");

        if ( inputStream != null ) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";

            while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
                stringBuilder.append('\n');
            }

            inputStream.close();
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
    }

    TextView output=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.logs);
    output.setText(stringBuilder);
}
```

Comment: where did you call saveText?

Comment: try putting in some logs on your saveText() function to see if you're getting the correct string before you're writing it out.

Comment: I am getting the write string but I am not sure why the function is somehow being called 2 times when I click on it